# Search and Replace strings containing dot, single and double quotes using bash script

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I need to search the string `cf['stack.over.flow']` in all the files of a folder and replace it with `STACK_OVER_FLOW` using bash script. I have tried many methods with `sed`, but no luck in escaping the single quotes and dot. Please help.

**EDIT:**
How to handle this for a string having double quotes.
***ex:*** `cf["stack.over.flow"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case of double quotes like `cf['stack.over.flow']`, you can use:

```
sed "s/cf\['stack\.over\.flow']/STACK_OVER_FLOW/" your_dir/*
```

For the case of double quotes like `cf["stack.over.flow"]`, you can use:

```
sed 's/cf\["stack\.over\.flow"]/STACK_OVER_FLOW/' your_dir/*
```

chaining the commands and adding a `-i` after `sed` and before the command will
perform the substitution in-place:

```
sed -i "s/cf\['stack\.over\.flow']/STACK_OVER_FLOW/" your_dir/* && 
sed -i 's/cf\["stack\.over\.flow"]/STACK_OVER_FLOW/' your_dir/*
```

Edit: @Jetchisel provided a way to do it with a single sed command:

```
sed -i "s/cf\[[\"']stack\.over\.flow[\"']\]/STACK_OVER_FLOW/" your_dir/*
```

The way it works is to match:

- the opening`cf\[`
- followed by either (escaped) double or single quotes: `[\"']`
- followed by the 'stack.over.flow' string (escaping the `.`): `stack\.over\.flow`
- followed again by either (escaped) double or single quotes: `[\"']`
- followd by the closing escaped square bracket: `\]`
- then replacing all the above by 'STACK_OVER_FLOW'

Comment: @mattb How to handle this for a string having double quotes. ex: cf["stack.over.flow"]

Comment: @AjayGanesan - for the case of double quotes, I'm not sure how to do it in a single command. I would just exchange single and double quotes in the commands (if that makes sense).

Comment: Really thanks. Both worked. By the way what's the logic.

Comment: `sed "s/cf\[[\"']stack\.over\.flow[\"']\]/STACK_OVER_FLOW/" file.txt` Look mah, only one `sed` :-)

Comment: @Jetchisel - very nice! Will you post that as a separate answer? If not I'll integrate it into my answer for future googlers and give you a shout out

Comment: @AjayGanesan, when you ask what's the logic, do you mean why do we need the `\` characters?

Comment: @mattb, post it. I don't need to add another answer, you have a working solution already.

Comment: yes @mattb from your solution, the search and replace portion of the command that works for cf['stack.over.flow'] is enclosed in double quotes and for the other one its vice versa. Is there any logic behind it?. Sorry for my ignorance, I am totally new to bash scripting.

Comment: @AjayGanesan - this page (https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html) explains it better than I ever could - also it has a
fantastic sed tutorial (https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) which I'm still
learning!